Trouble installing R package rnaturalearth and terra
I am trying to install the package rnaturalearth and when I run either:
devtools::install_github("ropensci/rnaturalearth") or install.packages(rnaturalearth)
it runs for a while and at the end, errors out at:
tools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.2.0/bin/x64 -lR
C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lblosc
C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lkea
C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsz
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'terra'
* removing 'C:/Users/ekallison/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/terra'

I then try to install terra either using:
remotes::install_github("rspatial/terra") or install.packages(terra)
it runs for a while and at the end, errors out at the same thing as above. Any idea what might be going on here? rtools was just installed and updated.
I tried to install rnaturalearth and terra packages, and instead of installing, I got an error as listed above.

See https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/881. Looks like you might need to use a newer version of RTools. Can you confirm which version you installed?

Thank you @MrFlick I have RTools version 44-6104-6039. I updated to the latest version yesterday when I tried this.

Your Rtools version should match your R version. You seem to be running R 4.2 given the output you've shown. Make sure to update your R to version 4.4 as well.

It seems that you are on windows and that the problem you have is trying to install the development version of "terra" from source code.
Instead, you could install the compiled version like this:
install.packages("terra")

After that:
install.packages("rnaturalearth")

If you think you need the development version of "terra", you can use the compiled version from R-Universe
install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')


HI @Robert Hijams. Same issue happens when Installing the compiled versions. I only tried installing the development versions because the original attempts like you suggested failed with the same error codes.

That simply cannot be true.  Installing the compiled version does not use RTools so you could never get the same messages. Please edit your question and show verbatim what happens when, in a fresh R session, you run install.packages("terra")

the issue was that my Rtools version didn't match my R version. The message is literally the exact same when I use the code you suggested I just get a pop-up message in R Studio that says the code needs to be compiled, are you sure you want to install? Anyways, it's fixed now after updating my R version to match R tools!

You should not need to compile and hence RTools should not matter. Apparently, R Studio guides you toward compiling the code where there should be no need for it.  Perhaps things like installing packages is easier outside of R Studio.
